# Database Design and the use of non-numeric Primary Keys

Tags: sql, database, database-design, primary-key, primary-key-design

I'm currently in the process of designing the database tables for a customer & website management application. My question is in regards to the use of primary keys as functional parts of a table (and not assigning "ID" numbers to every table just because).

For example, here are four related tables from the database so far, one of which uses the traditional primary key number, the others which use unique names as the primary key:

```
--
-- website
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `website` (
  `name` varchar(126) NOT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `notes` text NOT NULL,
  `website_status` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`name`),
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
  KEY `website_status` (`website_status`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- website_status
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `website_status` (
  `name` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `website_status` (`name`) VALUES
('demo'),
('disabled'),
('live'),
('purchased'),
('transfered');

--
-- client
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `client_status` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(46) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(78) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(56) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `zip` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `phone` text NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(78) NOT NULL,
  `notes` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `client_status` (`client_status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- client_status
---
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client_status` (
  `name` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `client_status` (`name`) VALUES
('affiliate'),
('customer'),
('demo'),
('disabled'),
('reseller');
```

As you can see, 3 of the 4 tables use their 'name' as the primary key. I know that these will always be unique. In 2 of the cases (the *_status tables) I am basically using a dynamic replacement for ENUM, since status options could change in the future, and for the 'website' table, I know that the 'name' of the website will always be unique.

I'm wondering if this is sound logic, getting rid of table ID's when I know the name is always going to be a unique identifier, or a recipe for disaster? I'm not a seasoned DBA so any feedback, critique, etc. would be extremely helpful.

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Welcome to a Holy war that has been waging since before you were born. :)

Comment: On a more serious note, one thing you are going to have to consider is the impact of a VARCHAR column in an Index. I'm not a seasoned DBA either, so I don't know the answer. But I would strongly recommend you fill up a test table, using a VARCHAR for a primary key, with a few million records and doing some testing. Then do the same with an INT as the primary key and see what happens.

Comment: Jordan is right about being concerned about a "wide" key like a varchar(126). See my answer below.

Comment: As a side note to anyone who is reading this that IS using foreign keys, thing about the amount of data you are passing around. In the example above 'website_status'.'name' -> 'website'.'website_status' that's at best 5 bytes and at worst 10 bytes for every record. Where if this design were to use a SMALLINT it would be a consistent 2 bytes (MySQL).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are 2 reasons I would always add an ID number to a lookup / ENUM table:

1. If you are referencing a single column table with the name then you may be better served by using a constraint
2. What happens if you wanted to rename one of the client_status entries?  e.g. if you wanted to change the name from 'affiliate' to 'affiliate user' you would need to update the client table which should not be necessary.  The ID number serves as the reference and the name is the description.

In the website table, if you are confident that the name will be unique then it is fine to use as a primary key.  Personally I would still assign a numeric ID as it reduces the space used in foreign key tables and I find it easier to manage.

EDIT:
As stated above, you will run into problems if the website name is renamed.  By making this the primary key you will be making it very difficult if not impossible for this to be changed at a later date.

Comment: Number two above is the best reason not to use the name as the primary key.

Comment: Good answer.
Here is one more reason:
String compare operation takes much longer time then numeric comparation.

Comment: Primary keys must NEVER carry data that is usable outside the database. That is, the only reason for keys to be used is to refer to records in the database, not to present the value of the keys to the user. The reason for this is that keys are _immutable_ and data is not. Name, gender, age, employee type, employee number, etc. are all changeable and should never be used as a key. Instead of using a bigint (or whatever) sequence, there is an argument for using a guid: http://bit.ly/gSIkOG

Answer (score 13):

When making natural `PRIMARY KEY`'s, make sure their uniqueness is under your control.

If you're absolutely sure you will never ever have uniqueness violation, then it's OK to use these values as `PRIMARY KEY`'s.

Since `website_status` and `client_status` seem to be generated and used by you and only by you, it's acceptable to use them as a `PRIMARY KEY`, though having a long key may impact performance.

`website` name seems be under control of the outer world, that's why I'd make it a plain field. What if they want to rename their `website`?

The counterexamples would be `SSN` and `ZIP` codes: it's not you who generates them and there is no guarantee that they won't be ever duplicated.

Comment: I have heard of two people being assigned the same SSN.  It isn't supposed to happen, but it has happened anyway, unless I'm misinformed.  A bigger problem is people using "counterfeit" SSNs in order to obtain employment.  Now your data source is corrupt, even if the Social Security Administration is managing SSNs correctly.

Comment: @Walter: my point exactly. SSN's should NOT be used as primary keys

Comment: I love the point about the uniqueness being under your control! We've even had supposedly unique interger id fields from customers that turned out to not be unique, when they reused them or went to a new system.

Answer (score 9):

Kimberly Tripp has an Excellent series of blog articles (*[GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/)* and *[The Clustered Index Debate Continues](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/)*) on the issue of creating clustered indexes, and choosing the primary key (related issues, but not always exactly the same). Her recommendation is that a clustered index/primary key should be:

1. **Unique** (otherwise useless as a key)
2. **Narrow** (the key is used in all non-clustered indexes, and in foreign-key relationships)
3. **Static** (you don't want to have to change all related records)
4. **Always Increasing** (so new records always get added to the end of the table, and don't have to be inserted in the middle)

Using "Name" as your key, while it seems to satisfy #1, doesn't satisfy ANY of the other three.

Even for your "lookup" table, what if your boss decides to change all *affiliate*s to *partner*s instead? You'll have to modify all rows in the database that use this value.

From a performance perspective, I'm probably most concerned that a key be *narrow*. If your website name is actually a long URL, then that could really bloat the size of any non-clustered indexes, and all tables that use it as a foreign key.

Answer (score 3):

Besides all the other excellent points that have already been made, I would add one more word of caution against using large fields as clustering keys in SQL Server (if you're not using SQL Server, then this probably doesn't apply to you).

I add this because in SQL Server, the primary key on a table by default also is the clustering key (you can change that, if you want to and know about it, but most of the cases, it's not done).

The clustering key that determines the physical ordering of the SQL Server table is also being added to every single non-clustered index on that table. If you have only a few hundred to a few thousand rows and one or two indices, that's not a big deal. But if you have really large tables with millions of rows, and potentially lots of indices to speed up the queries, this will indeed cause a lot of disk space and server memory to be wasted unnecessarily.

E.g. if your table has 10 million rows, 10 non-clustered indices, and your clustering key is 26 bytes instead of 4 (for an INT), then you're wasting 10 mio. by 10 by 22 bytes for a total of 2.2 billion bytes (or 2.2 GBytes approx.) - that's not peanuts anymore!

Again - this only applies to SQL Server, and only if you have really large tables with lots of non-clustered indices on them.

Marc

Comment: "you can change that, if you want to and know about it, but most of the cases, it's not done" - Only if the person designing the database isn't a good database designer. An experienced and qualified designer will take into account many things before deciding on what should be used in the clustered index.

Comment: Tom H: yes, of course - but a majority of app developers are not at the same time great database designers, in my own personal experience. Lots of app developers treat the database as a "dumb storage dump" where they can just drop their objects into - and don't think enough about database design.

Answer (score 2):

"If you're absolutely sure you will never ever have uniqueness violation, then it's OK to use these values as PRIMARY KEY's."

If you're absolutely sure you will never ever have uniqueness violation, then don't bother to define the key.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think you will run into trouble using this idea. As you end up with more parent child relationships, you end up with a huge amount of work when the names change (As they always will sooner or later). There can be a big performance hit when having to update a child table that has thousands of rows when the name of the website changes. And you have to plan for how do make sure that those changes happen. Otherwise, the website name changes (oops we let the name expire and someone else bought it.) either break because of the foreign key constraint or you need to put in an automated way (cascade update) to propagate the change through the system. If you use cascading updates, then you can suddenly bring your system to a dead halt while a large chage is processed. This is not considered to be a good thing. It really is more effective and efficient to use ids for relationships and then put unique indexes on the name field to ensure  they stay unique. Database design needs to consider maintenance of the data integrity and how that will affect performance.

Another thing to consider is that websitenames tend to be longer than a few characters. This means the performance difference between using an id field for joins and the name for joins could be quite significant. You have to think of these things at the design phase as it is too late to change to an ID when you have a production system with millions of records that is timing out and the fix is to completely restructure the databse and rewrite all of the SQL code. Not something you can fix in fifteen minutes to get the site working again.

Answer (score 1):

This just seems like a really bad idea.  What if you need to change the value of the enum?  The idea is to make it a relational database and not a set of flat files.  At this point, why have the client_status table?  Moreover, if you are using the data in an application, by using a type like a GUID or INT, you can validate the type and avoid bad data (in so far as validating the type).  Thus, it is another of many lines to deter hacking.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that a database that is resistant to corruption, even if it runs a little slower, is better than one that isn’t.

In general, surrogate keys (such as arbitrary numeric identifiers) undermine the integrity of the database.  Primary keys are the main way of identifying rows in the database; if the primary key values are not meaningful, the constraint is not meaningful.  Any foreign keys that refer to surrogate primary keys are therefore also suspect.  Whenever you have to retrieve, update or delete individual rows (and be guaranteed of affecting only one), the primary key (or another candidate key) is what you must use; having to work out what a surrogate key value is when there is a meaningful alternative key is a redundant and potentially dangerous step for users and applications.

Even if it means using a composite key to ensure uniqueness, I would advocate using a meaningful, natural set of attributes as the primary key, whenever possible.  If you need to record the attributes anyway, why add another one?  That said, surrogate keys are fine when there is no natural, stable, concise, guaranteed-to-be-unique key (e.g. for people).

You could also consider using index key compression, if your DBMS supports it.  This can be very effective, especially for indexes on composite keys (think [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structures), and especially if the least selective attributes can appear first in the index.

Answer (score 1):

I think I am in agreement with cheduardo. It has been 25 years since I took a course in database design but I recall being told that database engines can more efficiently manage and load indexes that use character keys. The comments about the database having to update thousands of records when a key is changed and on all of the added space being taken up by the longer keys and then having to be transferred across systems, assumes that the key is actually stored in the records and that it does not have to be transferred across systems anyway. If you create an index on a column(s) of a table, I do not think the value is stored in the records of the table (unless you set some option to do so).

If you have a natural key for a table, even if it is changed occassionally, creating another key creates a redundancy that could result in data integrity issues and actually creates even more information that needs to be stored and transferred across systems. I work for a team that decided to store the local application settings in the database. They have an identity column for each setting, a section name, a key name, and a key value. They have a stored procedure (another holy war) to save a setting that ensures it does not appear twice. I have yet to find a case where I would use a setting's ID. I have, however, ended up with multiple records with the same section and key name that caused my application to fail. And yes, I know that could have been avoided by defining a constraint on the columns.

Comment: There is no efficiency benefit to having `char` keys as opposed to numeric ones (neither is there, necessarily, any penalty). The key values *are* stored in the 'records' - all values are (except special, bulk value columns - but you won't be indexing those, anyway). Indexes *duplicate* the data they are covering. Those fields are never removed from the data just because they are indexed.

Comment: I suspect whether the data is stored in the table or not is an option. "The bottom, or leaf, level of the clustered index contains the actual data rows of the table. A table or view is allowed one clustered index at a time." I vaguely recall from my database theory class that you could store the values for indexed columns in the index so this data was not duplicated for every row of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Here few points should be considered before deciding keys in table

- Numeric key is more suitable when you
  use references ( foreign keys), since
  you not using foreign keys, it ok in
  your case to use non numeric key.
- Non-numeric key uses more space than
  numeric keys, can decrease
  performance.
- Numeric keys make db look simpler to
  understand ( you can easily know no
  of rows just by looking at last row)

Comment: The value of the numeric key for the last row isn't a good indication of the total number of rows in the database, unless you NEVER delete a record in your database.

Answer (score -1):

You NEVER know when the company you work for suddenly explodes in growth and you have to hire 5 developers overnight. Your best bet is to use numeric (integer) primary keys because they will be much easier for the entire team to work with AND will help your performance if and when the database grows. If you have to break records out and partition them, you might want to use the primary key. If you are adding records with a datetime stamp (as every table should), and there is an error somewhere in the code that updates that field incorrectly, the only way to confirm if the record was entered in the proper sequence it to check the primary keys. There are probably 10 more TSQL or debugging reasons to use INT primary keys, not the least of which is writing a simple query to select the last 5 records entered into the table.