# Which variable type to use when using text as primary key in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, key

I am aware about pros and cons of using a text as primary key in table
(there is [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517579/strings-as-primary-keys-in-sql-database)).

However I just wonder if I must use `varchar(10)` or `char(10)` or other

Values will look like 1-115115151  (length may differ)

Comment: Variable lenght - varchar.

Comment: I would use `char(n)` *only* for short strings (<= 5 chars) and those that are almost always the same length, e.g. ISO country codes, currency codes etc. - `char(n)` will **always** use `n` characters - padded with spaces, if you didn't provide `n` characters yourself --> `varchar(n)` is more flexible and efficient that way

Comment: What do those values represent?

Comment: the values come from another database (of my customer) and are actually the Primary key over there. For this I don't worry about being unique, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For that string, I would recommend varchar(11).

If the string length can grow EVER, I'd recommend making it 12 or even 15.

Varchar uses space equal to the number of characters in use + 2.  Data that can fit in either varchar(11) or varchar(15) will use the same amount space in both.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking you can use either, but agreed with the others here - you'll want to use varchar for variable length items.

- When your database scales and you start foreign keying from other tables there's a good chance you'll be happy you saved the space from not having a fixed character type.
- You'll also be very happy when/if, down the road, your key length winds up being longer than you'd anticipated.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use text datatype as a primary key, only integers. It's important for easier programming, and SQL connections.

Comment: This is not always the case, and the OP specifically states they are aware of this.