# SQL Query taking long time with joins

Tags: t-sql, indexing

I am just trying to understand why the below query is taking long time.

```
SELECT 
   t.dp_id
  ,d.hide_flag
  ,d.metadata_release_date
  ,d.run_code
  ,d.instrument_code
  ,r.s_region 
FROM sampledb1.dbo.xshooter t 
INNER JOIN sampledb2.dbo.dp_access d 
ON t.dp_id = d.file_id 
INNER JOIN sampledb3.dbo.raw r 
ON t.dp_id = r.dp_id 
WHERE t.dp_id = 'TEST'
```

All the tables have indexes on the columns they are joining in (actually they are the primary keys)

Comment: As the id is a string, it can affect performance. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517579/strings-as-primary-keys-in-mysql-database

Comment: If you run the query in SQL Server Management studio and turn on the query plan, it will tell you what it is doing and also recommend indexes that it needs.

Comment: You are joining across three Databases, are they at least on the same Server?

Comment: Does it take the time to show the result in SSMS? Have you tryed to insert it into a temp table? Try OPTION(FORCE ORDER)